# How do you use the html input required attribute to make one of a group of inputs required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the following input types: text, url, number, checkbox, radio, and file
In a group I want to require that at least one is provided in the form submission. Is it possible to remove the 'required' attribute when one of them is not empty. I'd like to also use the 'placeholder' attribute and not count it as an input. (I'm guessing the browsers take care of the 'placeholder' not being submitted)

```
<input type="text" name="TextInput1" id="TextInput1" value="" required>
<input type="url" name="urlInput1" id="urlInput1" value="" required>
<input type="number" name="numberInput1" id="numberInput1" value="" required>
```

Do these need to be grouped in some way? Do I need an 'onchange' handler? What is best?

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery code:

```
$("input").change(function() {
   $("input").attr("required", false);
});
```

you can customize it by adding classes and give the class instead of
"input".
and you can also make your own validation instead of using the browser's validation.
You can do it by adding to the form

```
onsubmit="return myValidation()"
```

and you can try using validations libraries:
http://parsleyjs.org/ 
http://verifyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want ?

```
$("input").change(function()
{
     $("input").removeAttr("required");
     $(this).attr("required","");
});
```

But it's not a good way

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/o6vhu9y4/

```
<input type="text" name="TextInput1" id="TextInput1" placeholder="place holder" value="" required>
<input type="url" name="urlInput1" id="urlInput1" value="" required>
<input type="number" name="numberInput1" id="numberInput1" value="" required>
<input type="submit" onClick="return validate()" />
<script>
    function validate(){
    var text1 = document.getElementById('TextInput1').value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById('urlInput1').value;
    var text3 = document.getElementById('numberInput1').value;
    var cnt = 0;

    if (text1.length > 0 || text2.length > 0 || text3.length > 0){
        alert("working");
        return true;
    }
    alert("please enter something");
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bt9u8263/1/)**

Try this code this example that handle event on `keyup`, adding a same class to every group in example class `group_1` and everytime the user hit some key inside one of the inputs check if one of them is not empty remove the `required` attribute :

**HTML :**

```
<input class='group_1' type="text" name="TextInput1" id="TextInput1" value="" required>
<input class='group_1' type="url" name="urlInput1" id="urlInput1" value="" required>
<input class='group_1' type="number" name="numberInput1" id="numberInput1" value="" required>
```

**JS :**

```
$('.group_1').keyup(function(){
    var removeRequired = false;

    $('.group_1').each(function(){
         if($(this).val()!="")
             removeRequired = true;
    });

    if(removeRequired)
        $('.group_1').removeAttr('required');
    else
        $('.group_1').attr('required', 'required');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you must observ all Inputs text in the same time, and so you pull off the required attribut.
I had the same problem and i did a function :

```
// -- This the array that contains the name of the attribute types (like ID or NAME) and their value. Ex: name="TextInput1" or id="TextInput1"
function inputs_required(vals=null){
    // -- This is the flag to get out the loop
    let i=0;
    // -- This is the string we build from the VALS array to assign the 3 inputs
    var input_string ="";
    // -- This is the loop that is used to build the string that will be used on the JQUERY object that we want to target, i.e. the INPUTS: var theinputs = $(input_string)
    $.each(vals,function(key,value){
        // -- We use the flag to know if we are on the first element to know if we must put a comma or not
        if(i>0) input_string+=",";
        // -- We create the desired string.This will give for example here : input[name=TextInput1,name=urlInput1,name=numberInput1]. We designate the objects to point with JQUERY
        input_string+="input["+value+"="+key+"]";
        // -- we increment the flag
        i++;
    });
    // -- The string is ready we pass it as an argument to JQUERY to create the object
    var theinputs = $(input_string);
    // -- We create the event listener of type INPUT (to avoid problems if it is not an input)
    theinputs.on('input', function () {
        // -- Here there 3 steps to understand, and we work on theinputs:
        // -- [1] !$(this).val().length : ici on vérifie si il y a un caractère de taper ou non sur l'élément INPUT courant qui a déclenché l'évènement
        // -- [2] prop('required' : ici on modifie la propriété REQUIRED à vrai ou faux en fonction de la première réponse [1]
        // -- [3] not(this) : ici on précise de ne pas changer la propriété REQUIRED sur l'élément qui a déclenché l'évènement.
        theinputs.not(this).prop('required', !$(this).val().length);
    });
}
// -- here we create a 2 dimensions array, it's a Javascript object, with the couple 'field name' : 'field type'.
// -- We can't put it in the opposite direction because it will create a confusion with the reserved keyword NAME
let inputsgroup = { "TextInput1": "name","urlInput1": "name","numberInput1": "name" };
// -- And finally we call the function with our array of INPUTS.
inputs_required(inputsgroup);
// -- I haven't done anything new compared to the others since we work with the REQUIRED attribute.
// -- But I wrote a function to make it very easy to reuse without rewriting the code.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P, Sorry, i think it was explicit ...
do you find the explaination better like that ?