# make text field required

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my text field required from a group of text field so that if any one is filled then the form will submit

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark d-flex">
    <p class="d-inline ps-1">l.</p>
    <p class="d-inline ps-4">Certified copy of OVD or equivalent e-document of OVD or OVD obtained through digital KYC process needs to be submitted (any one of the following OVDs)</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6 ps-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="OVD" class="check d-inline" required>
    <h4 class="d-inline">A. Passport Number</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="input form-control border-0" name="ovd">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6 ps-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="OVD" class="check d-inline" required>
    <h4 class="d-inline">B. Voter ID Card</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="input form-control border-0" name="ovd">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6 ps-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="OVD" class="check d-inline" required>
    <h4 class="d-inline">C. Driving Licence</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="input form-control border-0" name="ovd">
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit">
```

i want my form will submit if any of the field filled

Comment: Is there a reason why you added the JavaScript tag? If you have JavaScript code, please share it in your question. Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32744981/383904

Comment: this is part of a kyc form where any one of these document required and it is mandatory so i want user must fill any one of these field before submitting

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "required" from your input elements.

Instead of going with *type="submit"* , you will need to go with

```
  <button type="submit" onClick="check()"> Send </button>
```

Now, you will need to create some javascript function that checks if any of the input fields are filled, something like this:

```
<script>
 //first you need to take input fields inside variables
 var passportNumber = document.getElementsByName("OVD")[0].value; //cos it returns a list
 var IDcard = document.getElementsByName("ovd")[0].value; //like this for each field
 function check(){
  if(passportNumber || IDcard) //if ANY element has a value       
     return true;      
   else
     return false;
  }
</script>
```

Note: If you are beginner, you can **add this code inside of Head HTML element**, but better practice is to create an external JS file, and then call it.